# "Run this job" when sourceFolder contains a folder in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have Azure pipeline, i need to stop the pipeline when the sourceFolder doesn't contains a specific folder.

For Ex: if my sourceFolder contains
/home/vsts/work/1/s/projectName/src/app/pos - pipeline should run

if my sourceFolder contains
/home/vsts/work/1/s/projectName/src/app/ecomm - pipeline should not run

how do i mention the condition in Azure pipeline Demands / Custom Conditions?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? If it is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround , you can first create a custom variable(`RunPipeline`) with a value of `False`. Then add a new agent job, add a powershell task to this job, in the powershell task, traverse the source folders through the script, if there is a folder named `pos`, change the value of variable to `True`.

[image]

[image]

Sample inline script:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" |

Foreach-Object {​  
  if($_.Name --eq 'pos'){​ Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runPipeline;isOutput=true]True" }​
}​
```

Then add custom condition in the `Additional options` of the next job, for example: `eq(variables['RunPipeline'], 'True')`.

[image]